# Golang: можно ли передать в функцию массив аргументов, если она ожидает их через запятую?

Tags: golang

Функции, объявленной как

```
func Foo(query string, args ...interface{})
```

необходимо передать неизвестное число аргументов (argc), которые содержатся в массиве. Есть ли возможность это сделать, кроме как писать

```
foo(Q, arr[0], arr[1], .. arr[k])
```

?

Comment: `foo(Q, arr...)`

Comment: @Ainar-G, спасибо!